# Saving game data [Coins, Gems, Colors purchased with coins] in Swift

Tags: swift, game-center

Am I able to save game data like: coins, gems, colors bought with coins, backgrounds bought with coins to game center?

I am trying to figure out a way to save the data so if the user gets a new phone or deletes the game and re-downloads the game, their game center holds the data.

Or would I need to setup a database and have the user create an account to buy items so the items get stored in a database and they have to log in to get all their data back?